# detail about javascript callbacks

Tags: javascript

I am curious about something, imagine a link that closes the window. See the code below, and read the comments:

```
var a = document.querySelector('a');

//
// Since a.onclick requires a callback I have the following code:
//

a.onclick = function() { window.close() }; // This works fine.
a.onclick = function() { close() }; // This works as well.
a.onclick = () => { close() }; // This also work.
a.onclick = () => close(); // This works.

// But...

a.onclick = window.close; // This doesn't work.
a.onclick = close; // Neither this.

// But, why not?? Since onclick requires a function, and window.close is a 
// function and close is just the shorten way to call window.close?

// However...

a.onclick = close.bind(); // This works fine....
```

So fellows, since onclick receives a function, why to set just "close" does not do the job? It should "register" the function **close** (window.close) as the "callback" for that action, and call it when the event was triggered (like close.call());

I really don't understand this behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.

We are so used to seeing `window` holding all global variables that we have forgotten that `window` itself is an object. That's right - it's the object that represent the browser window.

And `close` is not merely a function but a method of the `window` object (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close).

Thus when you convert `close` to a function reference it loses it's binding to `this` (which should point to `window`).

The others work by happenstance:

1. `a.onclick = function() { window.close() };`

   This is obvious. You're calling the method directly so it gets the correct `this`.
2. `a.onclick = function() { close() };`

   A function that does not belong to any object will have it's this either pointing to the global object (`window`) or `undefined` if in strict mode. So when not in strict mode this will work.
3. `a.onclick = () => { close() };`

   Same explanation as number 2.
4. `a.onclick = () => close();`

   Same explanation as 3 but not using the optional `{}`.

Note: One may be tempted to think that 2, 3 and 4 are different mechanisms but while arrow functions affect how `this` behave you're not calling `this.close()`. Thus only the `this` value in `close` is important. The arrow functions don't change that.

Note that when not in strict mode the following should also work:

```
a.onclick = () => { this.close() }
```

I think it's fairly obvious from my previous explanations why the above should work.

Comment: but is still confusing why to set window.close still loses the context, since we are setting the "window" there, right before the function name.

Comment: That's because it will not be called as `window.close()` but `a.onclick()`. Thus the `this` is `a` not `window`

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the binding of the method to its `this`. When you have a `Function` reference to a method, then call it, it won't "know" which object the method belongs to (`this` will no-longer be a `Window`), so if `.close()` needs to know about its window object, the function call will fail.

`bind` works around this by fixing `this` to a particular object:

```
a.onclick = window.close.bind(window);
```